# In R how do you label the x-axis for T2 plots using mqcc?

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I am using the QCR library to draw the hotelling's T2 plot. I do not see any method/options in the document to update/modify the xaxis. I would like my hotelling Plot to be labeled. Anyone have a work around for this?

For Example

```
mqcc(mtcars)
```

gives the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxzQB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can create an appropriate object type (eg. mqcd, mqcs) using the QCR library and plot separately supplying xlabels with xlab parameter.</s>

Now that the question is edited and we are dealing with a different issue, I would suggest below as the starting point and build on it (format, colour etc.)

```
a1 <- mqcc(mtcars)
plot(a1$statistics,names(a1$statistics))
```

Comment: I wanted to modify the axes, not just the xlabel. This didnt work :(. Thanks for the answer

Comment: ok, you need to edit the question in that case as currently it is misleading. "I do not see any method/options in the document to update/modify the xlabels".

Comment: I agree. Thanks. Let me modify my question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the best solution so far. To insert label names. However, this does look ugly, and I am having difficulty rotating the axes

```
a <- mtcars
a1 <- mqcc(a,labels = rownames(a))
```

[Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxF4x.png)